# why does forwarding X11 over reverse ssh tunnel not work properly

Tags: x11, ssh-tunneling, xforwarding

I have a host which I want to access through reverse ssh and I also want to forward X11.
So I did this on the remote host:
`ssh -X -R 43022:localhost:22 usr@myhost -p 2222`
and I can connect fine with `ssh -X -p 43022 usr@localhost` from `myhost` but the X11 forwarding doesn't seem to work:

```
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display:
```

why is that?

Comment: Is `X11Forwarding` enabled in myhost's `sshd_config`?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Good point! Just double-checked and yes, it is. It also is enabled on the remote host

Comment: The error message shows that your DISPLAY environment variable is empty. That means that the -X flag was denied (in the second `ssh -X`; you don't need it in the first one). `X11Forwarding` is probably disabled on your *other* host, the one that runs `xeyes`. Don't you have a "X11 forwarding request failed" error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a *working DISPLAY* before X can be forwarded to you. Before your:

```
ssh -X -p 43022 usr@localhost
```

check with `echo $DISPLAY` and run `xeyes`. If the `$DISPLAY` is empty or if `xeyes` does not run ... X forwarding will not work, there's nothing to forward it to.